# how do I do a reverse proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, port-forwarding, ssl, webserver

I am fairly new to this, I would like to create a reverse proxy for me to be able to host multiple servers. So to get started will I have to change the port 80 on the web servers virtual host or can I just leave that? like for example in the header of the virtual host it has  would I have to change the 80? also I changed the web server to 80.80.80.80, 80.80.81.81, that is manual, do I change this to automatic if I use a reverse proxy? sorry for so many questions, but for the reverse proxy server, in the router settings, do I have that server ip port forwarded to port 80? last question as of now (sorry again if I have more in the future) if I already have a website that has an ssl certificate from cloudflare and I do the reverse proxy, would it affect it at all if the reverse proxy is done only on http? Thanks!

Comment: You should give a brief description of your intended physical / virtual server layout. It’s not clear the number of websites, number of servers, sites per server, logical topology, etc.  if you give a picture then it is much easier to describe what happens and how to configure it to your environment so we are all talking about the same thing. In addition, better formatting of your message would help readers to better find the points of interest.

Comment: I have a webserver currently hosting a website, I want to host another website but on a seperate server. how would I do that with a reverse proxy

Comment: check this answer https://serverfault.com/a/228446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will I have to change the port 80 on the web servers virtual host or can I just leave that?

The point of a reverse proxy is often to host multiple servers on a given port, so it's unlikely you will need to change any ports.

> Like for example in the header of the virtual host it has would I have to change the 80?

As long as you are using e.g. `<VirtualHost *:80>` (i.e. you aren't specifying an IP address e.g. `1.2.3.4:80`), leaving things as-is is likely fine.

> Also I changed the web server to `80.80.80.80`, `80.80.81.81`, that is manual, do I change this to automatic if I use a reverse proxy?

This looks like DNS for FreeNom. These settings are likely irrelevant.

> In the router settings, do I have that server IP port forwarded to port 80?

You need to have all incoming web requests for the reverse proxy forwarded to the reverse proxy. So if your reverse proxy (web server) is listening on port 80, your router needs to forward port 80 to your reverse proxy.

> If I already have a website that has an SSL certificate from CloudFlare and I do the reverse proxy, would it affect it at all if the reverse proxy is done only on HTTP?

If you are forwarding requests to the HTTPS site with a `Redirect`, probably not.